# Running a logistic regression on panel data

Tags: r, logistic-regression, panel-data

I want to do a logistic regression to calculate the probability of a student pursuing a master degree.

I have dataset containing many students who have done certain courses in certain years. These courses also receive a rating (as well does the tutor) and this is course and year specific.

These students may or may not do a master at the same university. Based on the results a student gets, bases on the rating a course gets, based on the number of resits a student does, I want to predict the probability of a student pursuing a master. 
To do so, I want to run a logistic regression and hence I need to split the data into a training and validation/test set. However, as you see, multiple rows can revolve around the same student. E.g. row 1 to 12 revolve around student 9000006.

The problem when doing a logistic regression now is that the regression sees every row as a seperate unit, while in fact, the students are kind of 'grouped'.

```r
      Programme Resits Student_ID Course_code Academic_year Course_Grade_Binned Graduated Master_Student Course.rating_M Rating.tutor_M Selfstudy_M
1            IB      0    9000006     ABC1198          2013                   B      TRUE              1             7.5            8.2        14.1
2            IB      0    9000006     ABC1192          2014                   B      TRUE              1             8.4            8.8        13.0
3            IB      0    9000006     ABC1277          2014                   A      TRUE              1             6.0            6.4        10.6
4            IB      0    9000006     ABC1448          2013                   B      TRUE              1             5.7            7.8        14.4
5            IB      0    9000006     ABC1120          2014                   B      TRUE              1             7.1            7.4        11.2
6            IB      0    9000006     ABC1362          2013                   B      TRUE              1             6.7            7.5        15.8
7            IB      0    9000006     ABC1213          2013                   C      TRUE              1             7.7            8.1        11.4
8            IB      0    9000006     ABC1382          2013                   B      TRUE              1             6.6            7.1        16.3
9            IB      0    9000006     ABC1108          2013                   C      TRUE              1             7.1            7.6        15.7
10           IB      1    9000006     ABC1329          2014                   B      TRUE              1             7.5            7.9        10.7
11           IB      0    9000006     ABC1126          2013                   B      TRUE              1             6.7            7.5        15.3
12           IB      0    9000006     ABC1003          2013                   B      TRUE              1             7.3            8.5        12.6
13           IB      0    9000014     ABC1309          2014                   B      TRUE              0             6.9            6.1        12.4
14           IB      0    9000014     ABC1198          2013                   A      TRUE              0             7.5            8.2        14.1
15           IB      0    9000014     ABC1277          2014                   A      TRUE              0             6.0            6.4        10.6
16           IB      0    9000014     ABC1448          2013                   A      TRUE              0             5.7            7.8        14.4
17           IB      0    9000014     ABC1362          2013                   B      TRUE              0             6.7            7.5        15.8
18           IB      0    9000014     ABC1213          2013                   B      TRUE              0             7.7            8.1        11.4
19           IB      0    9000014     ABC1152          2014                   A      TRUE              0             7.0            7.6        12.3
20           IB      0    9000014     ABC1382          2013                   A      TRUE              0             6.6            7.1        16.3
21           IB      0    9000014     ABC1108          2013                   B      TRUE              0             7.1            7.6        15.7
22           IB      0    9000014     ABC1455          2014                   A      TRUE              0             6.7            7.3        11.2
23           IB      0    9000014     ABC1126          2013                   B      TRUE              0             6.7            7.5        15.3
24           IB      0    9000014     ABC1003          2013                   A      TRUE              0             7.3            8.5        12.6
25           IB      1    9000028     ABC1213          2014                   C      TRUE              0             7.8            8.6        10.7
26           IB      0    9000028     ABC1198          2014                   B      TRUE              0             7.1            8.0        15.5
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to perform a logistic regression on this kind of data? If you have another suggestion to calculate a probability of a student pursuing a master, then please let me know as well :)

Cheers!

Comment: Basic approach: You could average the results by student, then run a simple model on it.... But this will remove the information about which course, to counter that a possible option is to spread the `Course_code` column into lots of different columns, with a 1 if the student did it, 0 if not, then run your model...

Comment: @HectorHaffenden thanks! I think indeed the best approach is to make 1 row per student. I just don't know how to proceed with that, as indeed, I would need a lot of columns for just the courses already.